# Store different arrays in Ionic Storage

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to use a submit page with a bunch of different fields on it to submit details about a single beehive (name, location, comments, etc.). I'm planning to use Ionic Storage, and have the data go into an array if that's the best way to do it, then use a list to display all the items, which you can then click to go to the specific details about the hive.

So far I'm trying to do something like this, but not sure if this is on the right track or not:

```
  submitHive() {
this.navCtrl.push(ViewHivePage)
let data={'name': this.name, 'location': this.location, 'address': this.address, 'date': this.date, 'weight': this.weight, 'comments': this.comments}
console.log(data)
this.hiveData={
  name:this.name,
  location:this.location,
  address:this.address,
  date:this.date,
  weight:this.weight,
  comments:this.comments
}
```

Pushing the data from the input fields, then going to a new page to display the details. I'm using `[(ngModel)]` to push the data, is this on the right track?
Thanks!

Comment: Your question is unclear . please describe more

Answer (score 0):

Better If You can use angular Forms instead of using multiple [(ngModel)]. Because of Angular Form implementation is more clear than this. Try to use like bellow

```
_dataForm: FormGroup;
_hiveData;

ngOnInit() {
    this.initForm();
}

initForm() {
    this._dataForm = new FormGroup({
     name: new FormControl("", Validator.required),
     ...
    });
}

saveData() {
    // check the validation if needs
    this.hiveData = this._dataForm.value;
    // save the data
    this.navCtrl.push(ViewHivePage, {hiveData: this.hiveData});
    // you can take this data from other component using navparams
}
```

**template**

```
<form [formGroup]="_dataForm">
 <input type="text" formControlName="name">
 ...
</form>
```